# Shim and Generic Methods

Tags: c#, generics, shim

I want to create a Shim for an Generic Method. But I have a bit a trouble with the Generic in that case.

Here is my example:

```
class BaseRepository <T> where T: Entity
{
    public T[] FindAll()
    {
        return Method<T>.FindAll()
    }
}

class ClassA : base<A>
{
}

class A : Entity
{
}

class ClassB : base<B>
{
}

class B : Entity
{
}
```

now I want to create a ShimMethod for ClassA and ClassB

```
ShimBaseRepository<A>.AllInstances.FindAll = (repo) => MethodA();
ShimBaseRepository<B>.AllInstances.FindAll = (repo) => MethodB();

public A MethodA()
{
    //Make the Same as MethodB
}

public B MethodB()
{
    //Make the Same as MethodA
}
```

But what if I have mor than 20 "Base" classes? I don't want to create a Delegate/method for every baseClass. I tried something like this:

```
List<Type> allEntityClasses = (from x in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Entity)).GetTypes()
                                    where !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface
                                    select x).ToList();

foreach(Type type in allEntityClasses=
{
    ShimBaseRepository<type????>.AllInstances.FindAll = (repo) => Method();
}

public Entity????? Method()
{
}
```

In my Unittest I will use the following methods:

```
ClassA.FindAll()
ClassB.FindAll()
```

and not:

```
Base.FindAll()
```

Edit:
I use Microsoft Fakes,so I can't Change anything in the ShimClass. Here is the generated sourcecode from Shim.

```
  public class ShimBaseRepository<T> : ShimBase<BaseRepository<T>> where T : Entity
  {
    public static class AllInstances
    {
        public static FakesDelegates.Func<BaseRepository<T>, T[]> FindAll { [ShimMethod("FindAll", 20)] set; }
    }
  }
```

My intention is, that I don't want to create a delegate for every entity, I just want to iterate through all my EntityClasses and create the delegate dynamically. But I have no Idea how I add my Type object in the

```
ShimBase<T>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You're showing us the solution that doesn't work, but not the problem you actually have. Also, please make sure you actually have sample code that can be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's discuss this a little. 
First of all, here is a straight-forward solution with virtual method:

```
public class Base<T> where T : Entity
{
    public virtual T[] FindAll()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then just override `FindAll` in concrete classes
Or, if you can, make `Base` abstract and `InnerFindAll` abstract too.

But, if you need to specify delegate in runtime (as i can see you have a specific Helper for it, but i can't get, why you invoke helper in Base and then you have some undefined in question AllInstances with a Func) this approach won't help. You'll need to implement [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with some default strategy assigned in Base. Then you'll have 3 ways to "resolve" strategies in concrete classes:

1. Hardcode a strategy in constructor of concrete class
2. Inject strategy to concrete class constructor via DI container
3. Implement some kind of Mapper which'll return you appropriate Strategy for EntityType (`T`)

Also, i think you have some troubles with design. I don't see any reason you need to implement FindAll as a lambda injected to a static property of type `Func<T>` (yep, i think you can replace `AllInstances.FindAll` with just a `static FindAll`). So if i were you, i'd use abstract method..

**EDIT**

Now i got your problem and can give you only a rather ugly solution via reflection... I hoghly don't recomend you to use this since it's really rigour

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Type> allEntityClasses = (from x in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Entity))
                                           .GetTypes().Where(t=>typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                       where !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface
                                       select x).ToList();
        foreach (var type in allEntityClasses)
        {
            var genericType = typeof(BaseGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            var helper = new DelegateHelper();
            var myLambda = helper.GetLambdaForType(type);
            var allInst = genericType.GetProperty("AllInstances").GetValue(null);
            if (allInst == null)
            {
                allInst = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType.GetProperty("AllInstances").PropertyType);
            }
            allInst.GetType().GetProperty("FindAll").SetValue(allInst,myLambda);
        }
    }


}

public static class BaseGeneric<T>
{
    public static AllInstances<T> AllInstances { get; set; }
}

public class AllInstances<T>
{
    public Func<T[]> FindAll { get; set; }
}

public class DelegateHelper
{
    public Delegate GetLambdaForType(Type type)
    {
        var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type.MakeArrayType());
        var methodInfo = typeof(DelegateHelper).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "FunctionMethod")
                                               .MakeGenericMethod(type);
        var @delegate = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(funcType, this);
        return @delegate;
    }

    public T[] FunctionMethod<T>()
    {   
        return new T[10];
    }
}

public  class Entity
{
}

public class EntityFirst
{

}

public class EntitySecond
{

}
```

Comment: I use Microsoft.Fakes for testing and don't wrote these classes. I just want to use it. I added the generated sourcecode from microsoft fakes.

Comment: It's also my first time with Microsoft Fakes and that's the reason for my problems.
I have my BaseRepository<T> where T : Entity
which get some data from an Interface. Now I write some Unittests and I don't want/can't go through this Interface. So I "Fake" this Interface and override the BaseRepository<T> methods. With
ShimBase<Entity>.AllInstances.FindAll = (repo) => Method();
I call my testmethod instead of the Interfacemethod. Now I have to create a delegate for every EntityClass, or the program try to go through the Interface.
But there are about 100 EntityClasses...

Comment: @wydy i updated my answer, please, let me know if this helps. It uses reflection a lot and so i find it really ugly and non-maintainable